# How to transform nested xml with complex namespaces using xsl?

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am trying to transform XML file to CSV format using XSL. Could anyone please help me, I have never used XSL previously. This is my first time.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<databook:databook xmlns:xsi="http://www.ww2g.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:databook="http://www.hello.com/arc/hi/model/databook" xsi:type="databook:HelloModelType">
<databook:property>
<version>1989</version>
<name>Current</name>
<fileName>Current</fileName>
<fileExtension>xls</fileExtension>
<description>Current Rates</description>
<created>2016-07-17-01.26.39.677445</created>
<databook:category id="1" name="Current"/>
<databook:datasheetNames>
<name>Current</name>
<name>Time</name>
</databook:datasheetNames>
</databook:property>
<databook:datasheet name="Current" isColumnBased="true">
<databook:columns>
<databook:column>
<databook:columnDefinition id="0" name="Gem" showName="Gem" type="String"/>
<cell>Gem</cell>
<cell>A1</cell>
<cell>A2</cell>
<cell>A3</cell>
</databook:column>
<databook:column>
<databook:columnDefinition id="0" name="IGT" showName="IGT" type="String"/>
<cell>IGT</cell>
<cell>B1</cell>
<cell>B2</cell>
<cell>B3</cell>
</databook:column>
</databook:columns>
</databook:datasheet>
<databook:datasheet name="Time" isColumnBased="true">
<databook:columns>
<databook:column>
<databook:columnDefinition id="0" name="Hello" showName="Hello" type="String"/>
<cell>Hello</cell>
<cell>C1</cell>
<cell>C2</cell>
<cell>C3</cell>
</databook:column>
<databook:column>
<databook:columnDefinition id="0" name="Hi" showName="Hi" type="String"/>
<cell>Hi</cell>
<cell>D1</cell>
<cell>D2</cell>
<cell>D3</cell>
</databook:column>
</databook:columns>
</databook:datasheet>
</databook:databook>
```

XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL /Transform"     xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/datasheet">
<xsl:for-each select="//datasheet">
<xsl:value-of select="@name" /> 
<xsl:for-each select="//column">
<xsl:apply-templates select ="cell" />
</xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="cell">         
<xsl:for-each select="//cell">
<xsl:value-of select="cell" />
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output below:

```
sheetname=Current
Gem,A1,A2,A3
IGT,B1,B2,B3
sheetname=Time
Hello,C1,C2,C3
Hi,D1,D2,D3
```

I want to iterate thru number of sheets, number of columns inside each sheet and then cell values under each column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:databook="http://www.hello.com/arc/hi/model/databook">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/databook:databook">
    <xsl:for-each select="databook:datasheet">
        <xsl:text>sheetname=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select=".//databook:column">
            <xsl:for-each select="cell">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each> 
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note (1) the use of a prefix to address those elements in the input XML that are in a namespace and (2) the difference between `//` and `.//`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) I will try this.

Comment: This piece of code was working previously     `<xsl:for-each select="databook:datasheet">
        <xsl:text>sheetname=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />`

Comment: @user2376404 Not sure what you mean by this. Does the above not work for you?

Comment: the above code is generating below output::  

1989
Current
Current
xls
Current Rates
2016-07-17-01.26.39.677445


Current
Time






Gem
A1
A2
A3



IGT
B1
B2
B3







Hello
C1
C2
C3



Hi
D1
D2
D3

Comment: @user2376404 **1.** Please don't post code in comments, it's unreadable. -- **2.** The above code is generating the **exact** output specified in your question - see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/6rewNxx

Comment: I m building it in java. there it doesnt seem to give proper output. is there a jar or something that needs to be added

Comment: @user2376404 I am afraid I don't know anything about Java. Perhaps you should ask a separate question about that. The above code should work with any XSLT processor.

Comment: Great it worked. I was using stylsheet with xsl extension, now i have changed it with .xslt. Thnaks a lot :)